# Child element is not getting selected in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a gridview that is being rendered as follows

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" rules="cols" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ucstockcount1_GridView1" style="color:Black;background-color:White;border-color:#DEDFDE;border-width:1px;border-style:None;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr style="color:White;background-color:#6B696B;font-weight:bold;">
        <th scope="col">Sr.no</th><th scope="col">Style</th><th scope="col">Stk Last Mon</th><th scope="col">Stk Received</th><th scope="col">Stk This Mon</th><th scope="col">Change</th><th scope="col">Price</th><th scope="col">Value</th>
    </tr><tr style="background-color:#F7F7DE;">
        <td>1</td><td>T1-34H</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>
                            <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucstockcount1$GridView1$ctl02$TextBox2" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ucstockcount1_GridView1_TextBox2_0" onblur="updatevals(&quot;ContentPlaceHolder1_ucstockcount1_GridView1_TextBox2_0&quot;,0,0,5.00,&quot;ContentPlaceHolder1_ucstockcount1_GridView1_Label1_0&quot;,&quot;ContentPlaceHolder1_ucstockcount1_GridView1_Label2_0&quot;)" />

                        </td><td>
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ucstockcount1_GridView1_Label1_0">0</span>
                        </td><td>5.00</td><td>
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ucstockcount1_GridView1_Label2_0">0</span>
                        </td>
    </tr><tr style="background-color:White;">
        <td>2</td><td>T1-43B</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>
                            <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucstockcount1$GridView1$ctl03$TextBox2" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ucstockcount1_GridView1_TextBox2_1" onblur="updatevals(&quot;ContentPlaceHolder1_ucstockcount1_GridView1_TextBox2_1&quot;,0,0,5.00,&quot;ContentPlaceHolder1_ucstockcount1_GridView1_Label1_1&quot;,&quot;ContentPlaceHolder1_ucstockcount1_GridView1_Label2_1&quot;)" />

                        </td><td>
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ucstockcount1_GridView1_Label1_1">0</span>
                        </td><td>5.00</td><td>
                            <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ucstockcount1_GridView1_Label2_1">0</span>
                        </td>
    </tr>
```

I use the following code to extract values at client side.

```
function updatea(grid) {
$('#' + grid + ' tr').each(function (i) {
    var style = "";
    var lastmon = 0;
    var received = 0;
    var thismon = 0;
    var change = 0;
    var price = 0;
    var value = 0;
    $(this).children('td').each(function (j) {
        if (j == 2) {
            style = $(this).html();
        } else if (j == 3) {
            lastmon = $(this).html();
        } else if (j == 4) {
            received = $(this).html();
        } else if (j == 5) {
            thismon = $(this).children('input').val().trim();
            alert(thismon);
        }
        //            else if (j == 6) {
        //                change = $(this).children('span').val().trim();
        //                alert(change);
        //            }
        //            alert($(this).html());
    });
});
```

}

Till 4th column I am able to get values as required but when i need to extract the value of a textbox that is inside the 5th column I get error TypeError: $(...).children(...).val(...) is undefined

I have taken the code from [Traverse html table using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032838/traverse-html-table-using-jquery)

please help. Thankx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index in `each()` is zero based, and the fifth TD doesn't have an input, the fourth has:

```
} else if (j == 4) {
    thismon = $(this).children('input').val().trim();
    alert(thismon);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Two problems, the index starts from `0` so column with index 4 has input element, second the first row does not have input element

```
function updatea(grid) {
    //start processing from row 1
    $('#' + grid + ' tr').slice(1).each(function (i) {
        var style = "";
        var lastmon = 0;
        var received = 0;
        var thismon = 0;
        var change = 0;
        var price = 0;
        var value = 0;
        $(this).children('td').each(function (j) {
            if (j == 1) {
                style = $(this).html();
            } else if (j == 2) {
                lastmon = $(this).html();
            } else if (j == 3) {
                received = $(this).html();
            //column 5 has index 4
            } else if (j == 4) {
                thismon = $(this).children('input').val().trim();
                alert(thismon);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6j7TQ/)

Answer (score 1):

You can make selections easier this way

```
$('#' + grid + ' tr').slice(1).each(function (i) {
    var style = $('td:eq(1)', this).html();
    var lastmon = $('td:eq(2)', this).html();
    var received = $('td:eq(3)', this).html();
    var thismon = $('td:eq(4) input', this).val();
}
```

+1 to @arun-p-johny for `.slice(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes val() function didn't work for me in some conditions. You may test `attr('value')` instead of `val()` or you can change children() to `$($(this).find('input')).val().trim()` or `$(this+'input').val().trim()` or `$(this).children().val().trim()`

So I don't really remember right now but sometimes the returning object is not DOM Object.

Finally you can test `$($(this).children('input')).val().trim()`.

As you can see there are too much moves to find anything. I just focused the main problem, so you need to test these and if any of them don't work, just tell me.

But I think the main problem is returning value is not DOM object. So it tries to reach non object and it gives error.